# What are the differences among L'\x1234', '\u1234', u'\x1234' and L'\u1234' in C?

Tags: c, character, literals

What are the differences among `L'\x1234'`, `'\u1234'`, `u'\x1234'` and `L'\u1234'` in C (C11 and newer versions)?

Apparently a character constant with prefix `L` is of type `wchar_t` and a constant with prefix `u` is of type `char16_t`. An escape sequence starting with `\x` means the character with the given code in the Execution Character Set (ECS) of the compiler and an escape sequence starting with `\u` means the character with the given code in UTF-16.

What is the type of `'\u1234'` (without the prefix `L`)? What is the integer value of `L'\u1234'`? The code of the character with UTF-16 code 0x1234 in the ECS? Does the character denoted by `u'\x1234'` has a UTF-16 code of 0x1234 or it depends on the ECS?

Comment: The expression `'\u1234'` is a multi-byte character, and it's implementation-defined how those are handled (i.e. different compilers might treat them differently).

Answer (score 2):

> What is the type of `'\u1234'` (without the prefix `L`)?

The type of `'\u1234'` is `int`. If `CHAR_MAX` is greater than or equal to 0x1234 (4660) then the value of `'\u1234'` is 0x1234 (4660). Otherwise, the value of `'\u1234'` is implementation-defined.

> What is the integer value of `L'\u1234'`?

The type of `L'\u1234'` is `wchar_t`. If the value 0x1234 (4660) exists as a member of the extended character set and it represents the character designated by the universal character name `\u1234` in the source character set then the value of `L'\u1234'` is 0x1234 (4660). Otherwise the value of `L'\u1234'` is implementation-defined.

> The code of the character with UTF-16 code 0x1234 in the ECS?

0x1234 is not a character constant. Whether there is a single member of the extended execution character set, a sequence of more than one member of the extended execution character set, or no sequence of members of the extended execution character set that represents a character corresponding to UTF-16 code 0x1234 is implementation-defined.

> Does the character denoted by `u'\x1234'` has a UTF-16 code of 0x1234 or it depends on the ECS?

The type of `u'\x1234'` is `char16_t`. The value of `u'\x1234'` is 0x1234 (4660). A program may interpret the value 0x1234 (4660) as a UTF-16 code unit value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, according to the last paragraph `u'\x1234'` and `u'\u1234'` have the same value. I'm not quite sure.